# Customise Ngx-toastr in angular 6 with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, notifications, ngx-toastr

Hii All i am implementing Ngx-toastr in angular 6 with typescript my problem is that i can't make it beautiful as i want because i dont't know which css is override on that **ngx-toastr** class i wrote some css on **Style.css** File **ngx-toastr** and i want `border-radius: 15px;` but inner part not taking rounded corner with `border-radius: 15px;` I search many resource from the internet but not getting proper output and i Can't Change other toastr Because in my project something around **350+ Component** i don't want to change on every file with method that's why i want to customize existing toastr CSS.

This is my Css Code

```
.toast-container .ngx-toastr {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    background-position: 15px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999;
    color: #fff;
    border-image-source: linerar-gradient(red,purple) !important;
    border: 4px solid green !important;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(red, purple) !important;
    border-image-slice: 20 !important;
}

.toast-success {
    background-color: #51a351;
}
```

But My Expectation is I want same as in this picture if u want to check then visit this link and click on **RESET** button to show toastr [Click Here to visit that site](https://piaf-vue.coloredstrategies.com/user/forgot-password)

[image]

Here is my [StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnt8nz)

Comment: Can you change the border to 2px solid red !important, and see whether this is something you want.

Comment: no i want some more rounded corner something like `border-radius: 15px;`

Comment: yeah that is still there. Keep the border-radius to 15px but just change the border thickness and color

Comment: but you can check inner part not rounded still it with corner i want inner part also border-radius

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After Override this CSS in your **Style.css** File. I was able to customize this ngx-toastr with overriding this CSS

> Note: Before overrride this css please check toastr class from dev
>   tool console or inspect the element

```
.toast-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(purple,red) !important;
  border-radius: 22px !important; 
  box-shadow: -5px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
  margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}

.toast-container .toast {
  margin: 2px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.toast-success{
  background-image: none !important;
}

.toast-success::after{
  content: '\f00c' !important;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 14px !important;
  left: 15px !important;
  color: #333 !important;
  font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

.toast-title{
  color: purple !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

.toast-message{
  color:#8f8f8f !important;
}
```

Comment: What if I need to do it from a component?

Answer (score 1):

Remove White Box shadow you can use,

```
.toast-container .ngx-toastr {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #3b3b3b !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove "border-image-source" from the css

```
.toast-container .ngx-toastr {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    background-position: 15px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999;
    color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid green !important;
}
```

[image]

Also you can make a custom toast as your requirement. Please follow a below link to make a custom toast.

https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/master/src/app/pink.toast.ts

Comment: what is your issue? you want to make a red border around the toast?

Comment: Check I have added the screenshot for you.

Comment: but want gradient color on border on know this without gradient i solve this but not solving gradient color on border